# Logstash kibana geoip filter conflict

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, logstash, kibana, geoip

I have been trying to make Geo Filter working for logs. No luck yet.

I keep recreating my Logstash Index in ES, recreating GeoIP field with with Default type, double, and float, but Kibana keep complaining that my geoip.location property has Conflict.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
geoip {
  source => "[headers][x-forwarded-for]"
  target => "geoip"
  database => "/etc/logstash/GeoLiteCity.dat"
  add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][longitude]}" ]
  add_field => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "%{[geoip][latitude]}"  ]
}
mutate {
  convert => [ "[geoip][coordinates]", "float"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue by specifying default Mapping template, and recreating index now has "geo_point" data type for geoip.location.

Comment: Ok, please give a bit more detail. Ant configs that needed changing or did you change it in kibana settings? Or reindex with elasticsearch?

Comment: reindexed the index in ES with mapping file

Comment: Yeah, how did you do that? Please be explicit..the exact command and configs.

Comment: Take a look at the example here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html